# Portable Python importing module strange behaviour

Tags: python, python-import

I get strange behaviour on Portable Python 2.7.6 Pyscripter 2.5.3.
In my code line:

```
from opendeep.data.dataset import MemoryDataset
```

gives:

> ImportError: No module named data.dataset

but only when reinitialising interpreter (re-executing the whole file). Notice that error message is not:

> ImportError: No module named opendeep.data.dataset

When I send this line of code to remote interpreter individually, then everything runs fine - module is imported. Any suggestions? I'd like to debug my code, which is impossible in these circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be okay to show me the details of your python path?

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Only thing I can think of is there's another module or file somewhere on the path with a similar name, but it's hard to tell without information on installed packages, contents of the directory your running a script/the interpreter on and so on.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Apologies I am quite new.

Comment: BINGO!!! Great intuition duFF.

My mistake was to name my code file "opendeep.py", the same as library I was trying to import. Changed file name and it's OK now.

Thanks for help **duFF**

Answer (score 0):

BINGO!!! Great intuition **duFF**.

My mistake was to name my code file "opendeep.py", the same as library I was trying to import. Changed file name and it's OK now.

Thanks for help **duFF**.

Comment: These should be comments, if his answer helped you I would also recommend you to accept his answer (by clicking on the tick mark to the left of his answer) .